# I've added the Daily PPA and Appstream causes an error when trying to upgrade

Tags: updates, apt, development, ppa

I've added the Daily PPA (don't worry, I have another partition with a stable elementary, this is just for learning) and when I try to `apt upgrade -f` (or the same without the -f) I get the following error:

```
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree       
 Reading state information... Done
 Correcting dependencies... failed.
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 appstream-data-pantheon-icons : Depends: appstream-data-pantheon but it is not installed
 E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages. E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

I've tried to `apt install -f appstream-data-pantheon-icons` :

```
appstream-data-pantheon-icons is already the newest version (0.3.0-0~11~ubuntu0.4.1).
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
appstream-data-pantheon-icons : Depends: appstream-data-pantheon but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

And then `apt install -f appstream-data-pantheon`:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
   appstream-data-pantheon
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
83 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/66,1 kB of archives.
After this operation, 74,8 kB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 181367 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../appstream-data-pantheon_0.3.0-0~11~ubuntu0.4.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking appstream-data-pantheon (0.3.0-0~11~ubuntu0.4.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/appstream-data-pantheon_0.3.0-0~11~ubuntu0.4.1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/app-info/yaml/pantheon_xenial-main_amd64.yml.gz', which is also in package appstream-data-pantheon-loki-stable 0.4+r13~ubuntu0.4.1
Processing triggers for appstream (0.10.4-1~elementary0.4.1) ...
AppStream cache update completed successfully.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/appstream-data-pantheon_0.3.0-0~11~ubuntu0.4.1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What do I do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see there is a conflict between two packages (`appstream-data-pantheon` and `appstream-data-pantheon-loki-stable`) that both want to install a file (`/usr/share/app-info/yaml/pantheon_xenial-main_amd64.yml.gz`).

You can try to (in this order, preferably):

1. wait for the bug to be corrected :)
2. remove the older package if you do not need it any more

   ```
   sudo apt autoremove appstream-data-pantheon-icons
   ```
3. choose to overwrite the selected file

   ```
   sudo dpkg --install --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/appstream-data-pantheon_0.3.0-0~11~ubuntu0.4.1_all.deb
   ```

Comment: I don't know why I need appstream or what it does. But what's the best approach, 2 or 3?

Comment: I would try 2 and 3 only if 2 does not work

Comment: `sudo apt autoremove appstream-data-pantheon-icons `

That did the trick. Thanks!